# Program for Backup - Python

Tags: python-2.7

Im trying to execute the following code in Python 2.7 on Windows7. The purpose of the code is to take back up from the specified folder to a specified folder as per the naming pattern given.

However, Im not able to get it work. The output has always been 'Backup Failed'.

Please advise on how I get resolve this to get the code working.

Thanks.

Code :

```
backup_ver1.py

import os
import time
import sys

sys.path.append('C:\Python27\GnuWin32\bin')
source = 'C:\New'
target_dir = 'E:\Backup'
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target,''.join(source))
print('This is a program for backing up files')
print(zip_command)

if os.system(zip_command)==0:
print('Successful backup to', target)
else:
print('Backup FAILED')
```

Comment: You already print the zip command; have you tried copying it exactly and executing it from the command line? Then you will see the error it outputs.

Answer (score 1):

See if escaping the \'s helps :-

```
source = 'C:\\New'
target_dir = 'E:\\Backup'
```

Comment: Or use "raw" string literals: `source = r'C:\New'`

Comment: Tried on my system but it shows the errors on the console. You don't see any errors on the console?

Comment: I was trying with IDLE. I tried executing from Command Prompt now, I get the following error: " 'zip" is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". Any idea whats the way out of this - where am I wrong?

Comment: Add the path to the zip program to the environment variable

Comment: I thought this line does the job : "sys.path.append('C:\Python27\GnuWin32\bin')". Is it not?

Comment: sys.path contains the list of directories where python searches for modules. This one is a program that is executed in a shell.

Comment: Can you advise on how can I add the path to the zip program to the environment variable.

Comment: See http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx and add the path upto zip program there

Comment: Remember to start a new cmd window after adding. Please post your updated PATH variable, the path to zip program and the error you see.

Comment: Or better still consider using a batch file instead if you don't expect significant extensions to this script :)